# FineUploader S3 browser direct upload: chunking enabled POST to AWS fails: 403 SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

For files less than 5mb my configuration is working to upload. For files larger than 5mb they always fail with Post response from AWS:

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>..
```

I am using NodeJS, with the relevant functions from the demo s3handler.js unchanged eg: the signRestRequest() function appears to be working as expected per this documentation:

http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/08/16/fine-uploader-s3-upload-directly-to-amazon-s3-from-your-browser/#support-chunking

For files less than 5mb with this configuration, resume works if the connection is closed and then re-open automatically.  I am hosting the page and NodeJS in the same local Ubuntu VM. My browser side configuration:

```
$('#fineUploader').fineUploaderS3({
        request: {            
            endpoint: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket-name-redacted/",
            accessKey: "keyredacted",                
        }, 
        signature: {
            endpoint: "http://192.168.1.203:8000/s3handler"
        },
        uploadSuccess: {
            endpoint: "http://192.168.1.203:8000/s3UploadSuccess"
        },
        retry: {
            enableAuto: true 
        },
        chunking: {
            enabled: true //not working
        },
        resume: {
            enabled: true 
        }            
    });
```

This is the response before it is SHA1 HMac encoded, then base64 encoded:

```
POST

application/pdf

x-amz-acl:private
x-amz-date:Fri, 05 Jun 2015 19:26:17 GMT
x-amz-meta-qqfilename:filename.pdf
/bucket-name/13af5c15-ba04-4375-a6f9-25c2691ed827.pdf?uploads
```

My temporary test S3 Bucket CORS configuration:

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>x-amz-acl</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>x-amz-meta-qqfilename</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>x-amz-date</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>x-amz-server-side-encryption</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>authorization</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>

</CORSRule>
```

I can provide any additional information as required and have purchased a license.  Thanks!!

This is the header sent to the AWS post for a multi-part upload:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If AWS reports that your signature is incorrect, then the issue is with your signature generation code. As documented, chunked requests (by default files greater than 5 MB) use S3's multipart upload API, and the signature requirements are different.

The following is from Fine Uploader's documentation, specific to chunked uploads:

> ### Chunked Uploads
>
> Fine Uploader S3 uses Amazon S3's REST API to initiate, upload, complete, and abort multipart uploads. The REST API handles authentication by signing canonically formatted headers. This signing is something you need to implement server-side. All your server needs to do to authenticate and supported chunked uploads direct to Amazon S3 is sign a string representing the headers of the request that Fine Uploader sends to S3. This string is found in the payload of the signature request:
>
> { "headers": /* string to sign */ }
>
> The precense of this property indicates to your sever that this is, in fact, a request to sign a REST/multipart request and not a policy document.
>
> This signature for the headers string differs slightly from the policy document signature. You should NOT base64 encode the headers string before signing it. All you must do, server-side, is generate an HMAC SHA1 signature of the string using your AWS secret key and then base64 encode the result. Your server should respond with the following in the body of an 'application/json' response:
>
> { "signature": /* signed headers string */ }

[Fine Uploader's server-examples repo even includes a full node.js example that handles chunked and non-chunked signing logic.](https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/blob/master/nodejs/s3/s3handler.js)

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I am using the s3handler.js that you linked to already.  It works, except when I enable the chunking option browser-side.  Any other suggestions for me to continue troubleshooting this?

Comment: Your next step should be to verify that your endpoint is returning the correct signature to fine uploader, and then that this signature is being sent to s3 properly without any additional headers not accounted for when generating the signature.

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant, but I added two lines of code to enable CORS in your s3handler.js file.

Comment: The nodeJS endpoint is returning the signature generated by the code provided in s3hanlder.js for multi-part uploads. It is provided this by the fileUploaderS3 object in the browser.  I verified the response to the post matches in the browser and console.log() output from node.

Comment: This is all F.U. code involved, nothing I wrote.  Since the client access key works when chunking is turned off I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this. It's either a bug in the example code, or perhpas something is not configured correctly on the S3 CORS?

Comment: No, not a CORS issue. If S3 is complaining about a bad signature then there is likely some additional header or headers sent with one of the multipart upload REST calls to S3.

Comment: This is the header which is sent by the fineUploaderS3 browser side object in the initial post?  I have included that in my question in plain-text, the s3handler.js detects this correctly as a multi-part and returns only the signature.  Does the header listed above appear correctly formatted? There is no marker for chunked uploads, but the second post which goes to AWS is marked as chunked.  It is this post to AWS that gets the 403.

Comment: There are definitely some differences between the headers you just posted and the string sent to the signature server you posted previously. Was this an oversight on your part?

Comment: I did not have the data from my initial post, the attached image shows an actual file name. On the initial post, I redacted my bucket and filename. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I am only trying to get the demo s3handler.js for Node you linked to working with a basic FU object, specified in my post.  It works, except if the file is larger than 5mb and chunking is enabled.  This is where I am stuck.

Comment: If i can provide console output from any functions, or browser variables. I can attach my s3handler.js and simple web project as a zip link.

Comment: If you can provide a link to a site where this can be reproduced, perhaps that will be useful.

Comment: I've been seeing this too. What's weird, is I can only replicate it on computers that aren't my development computer. Even when I run my local server and hit it from another machine I can see the issue. I hate to be saying "I see this too" without any additional help/working examples... I'll see if I can put something together.